# "Array" usage in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to create a temp table where the `AlphaSeq` column would go through an "array" of alphanumeric characters that do not repeat and follow a flow as shown in the example below.

Example:

| AlphaSeq | NumericSeq |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A1 | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B1 | 4 |
| AA | 5 |
| AB | 6 |
| BA | 7 |
| BB | 8 |
| [ETC] | [ETC] |

Here's what I have so far (Obviously the "IG" is static as it is written now, so Im trying to make that field more fluid)

```
CREATE TABLE #Index 
(
     AlphaSeq VARCHAR(2), 
     NumericSeq TINYINT
)

DECLARE @ArrayNum AS TINYINT;
DECLARE @ReceiptSeq AS VARCHAR(2);

SET @ArrayNum = 0
SET @ReceiptSeq = 'IG'

WHILE @ArrayNum < 100
BEGIN 
    SET @ArrayNum = @ArrayNum + 1

    INSERT INTO #Index (AlphaSeq, NumericSeq)
    VALUES (@ReceiptSeq, @ArrayNum)
END

SELECT *
FROM #Index
```

Comment: I would suggest you get a list of all the charcters you need, and `CROSS JOIN` them to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cross-join the list of characters

```
CREATE TABLE #Index 
(
     AlphaSeq VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
     NumericSeq SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY
);

WITH Chars AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
      ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')
    ) v(chr)
),
CharsWithNums AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
      ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('0')
    ) v(chr)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Chars
)
INSERT #Index (AlphaSeq)
SELECT chr AS AlphaSeq
FROM Chars
UNION ALL
SELECT a.chr + b.chr
FROM Chars a
CROSS JOIN CharsWithNums b
ORDER BY AlphaSeq;
```